# Pubnub with py2app throwing [Errno 20] Not a directory

Tags: python, py2app, pyobjc, pubnub

I have a simple Pubnub code where I publish to a channel and then consume the messages in that channel. I works the way it should when I run it as a standalone program. However, if I package this using py2app, I keep getting the following error:

`[Errno 20] Not a directory`

Here is the code:

```
from Pubnub import Pubnub
from threading import Thread
from hashlib import md5

def trace(msg):
    from Foundation import NSLog
    NSLog(str(msg))

# Class to be called in a seperate thread
class Subscriber(Thread):

    def __init__(self, func_obj, channel_name):
        ''' Constructor. '''
        Thread.__init__(self)
        self.channel_name = channel_name
        self.func_obj = func_obj
        trace("thread init ")

    def run(self):
        trace("run")
        self.func_obj(self.channel_name)


class ManageSubscription(object):

    def __init__(self):
        self.pusher_obj = Pusher()

    def publish_to_channel(self, channel_name, message):
        self.pusher_obj.publish(channel_name, message)

    def subscribe_to_channel(self, channel_name):
        trace("subscribe to channel1")
        try:
            self.pusher_obj.subscribe(channel_name)
        except Exception as e:
            trace(e)

    def unsubscribe_to_channel(self, channel_name):
        trace("Unsubscribe to channel")
        self.pusher_obj.disconnect()


class Pusher(object):

    pubnub = None

    def __init__(self):
        if not Pusher.pubnub:
            Pusher.pubnub = Pubnub(PUBNUB_KEYS['publisher'],
                                   PUBNUB_KEYS['subscriber'],
                                   PUBNUB_KEYS['secret'],
                                   ssl_on=True,
                                   origin=PUBNUB_KEYS['domain'])

    @staticmethod
    def error(msg):
        # import osx.tray as tray
        trace('Came to error' + msg)
        # trace(msg)
        # tray.notify.notify('Deleted', 'subtitle', 'description text', 'http://google.com')
        # trace(msg)
        return True

    @staticmethod
    def connect(msg):
        # import osx.tray as tray
        trace('Came to connect')
        # trace(msg)
        # tray.notify.notify('Deleted', 'subtitle', 'description text', 'http://google.com')
        # trace(msg)
        return True

    @staticmethod
    def get_message(msg, msg1):
        # import osx.tray as tray
        trace('Came to callback')
        trace(msg)
        trace(msg1)
        # tray.notify.notify('Deleted', 'subtitle', 'description text', 'http://google.com')
        # trace(msg)
        return True

    @staticmethod
    def subscribe(channel_name):
        trace("Came to subscriber")
        pp_channel = 'channel_id_goes_here'
        Pusher.pubnub.subscribe(channels=pp_channel, callback=Pusher.get_message, connect=Pusher.connect, error=Pusher.error)
        trace('done')

    @staticmethod
    def publish(channel_name, message):
        trace("Came to publish")
        Pusher.pubnub.publish('channel_id_goes_here', message, callback=Pusher.connect, error=Pusher.error)
        trace('done')


subscription_manager = ManageSubscription()
subscription_manager.publish_to_channel('channel_id_goes_here', 'I published this')
thread1 = Subscriber(subscription_manager.subscribe_to_channel, 'channel_id_goes_here')
thread1.start()
```

Comment: So this is very strange indeed!  I've pasted my output of your code below.  Looks healthy yes?

Comment: Thanks. But I am not facing any issues when I run the program directly. The problem happens only when I package it with py2app and then run the application generated.

Comment: Email support@pubnub.com if you are still experiencing issues, and we'll resolve 'em in a GIFFY!

Comment: Thank you. I sent a mail to pubnub support.

Answer (score 0):

I've run your program and I receive the following Output:

```
2014-08-13 22:26:57.190 Python[10435:1107] Came to publish
2014-08-13 22:26:57.201 Python[10435:1107] done
2014-08-13 22:26:57.201 Python[10435:1107] thread init 
2014-08-13 22:26:57.202 Python[10435:301b] run
2014-08-13 22:26:57.202 Python[10435:301b] subscribe to channel1
2014-08-13 22:26:57.203 Python[10435:301b] Came to subscriber
2014-08-13 22:26:57.203 Python[10435:301b] done
2014-08-13 22:26:57.337 Python[10435:2b2f] Came to connect
2014-08-13 22:26:57.350 Python[10435:3203] Came to connect
```

Looks like this:

[image: PubNub Python PIP Package Demo Code]

And `PIP FREEZE` is as follows:

```
pip freeze | grep pubnub
pubnub==3.5.2
pubnub-console==3.5.0
```

Image screenshot of PubNub PIP Freeze:

[image: PubNub pip freeze console output]